# Variable assigned with the output of GREP (grep -fxq) command empty

Tags: bash, shell, unix, grep

I'm trying to store the result of grep command to a variable.

Created a file chkk.txt with following content ::

**abc dvf ghi rfg**

```
tmp=$(grep -c "abc" /tmp/chkk.txt)
echo $tmp
1
```

But when grep is used with fxq argument, the variable 'tmp 'is empty

```
tmp=$(grep -Fxq "abc" /tmp/chkk.txt)
echo $tmp
```

I would like understand the reason as to why GREP with -fxq argument isn't working in this case ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

man grep:

```
   -q, --quiet, --silent
          Quiet;  do  not  write  anything  to  standard   output.    Exit
          immediately  with  zero status if any match is found, even if an
          error was detected.  Also see the -s or --no-messages option.
```